# Why is the QScrollArea restricted in size?

Tags: c++, qt, qscrollarea, qlayout, qt5.9

To my custom widget, inherited from *QWidget*, I have added a *QScrollArea* like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)//MainWindow is a QWidget
{
    auto *scrollArea = new QScrollArea(this);
    auto *widget = new QWidget(this);

    widget->setStyleSheet("background-color:green");

    scrollArea->setWidget(widget);
    scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
    scrollArea->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded);
    QVBoxLayout *parentLayout = new QVBoxLayout(widget);

    this->setStyleSheet("background-color:blue");

    for(int i=0;i<12;i++){
        QHBoxLayout* labelLineEdit = f1();
        parentLayout->addStretch(1);
        parentLayout->addLayout(labelLineEdit);
    }

    parentLayout->setContentsMargins(0,0,40,0);
}

QHBoxLayout* MainWindow::f1()
{

    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;

    QLabel *label = new QLabel("Movie");
    label->setStyleSheet("background-color:blue;color:white");
    label->setMinimumWidth(300);
    label->setMaximumWidth(300);

    layout->addWidget(label);

    QLineEdit *echoLineEdit = new QLineEdit;
    echoLineEdit->setMaximumWidth(120);
    echoLineEdit->setMaximumHeight(50);
    echoLineEdit->setMinimumHeight(50);

    echoLineEdit->setStyleSheet("background-color:white");

    layout->addWidget(echoLineEdit);

    layout->setSpacing(0);

    return layout;
}
```

This produces a window which looks like this:

[image]

The problem is, that I want the `scrollArea` to occupy the entire window, but it does not. It also doesn't get resized when I resize the window.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Why your _MainWindow_ is inheriting from _QWidget_ and not from _QMainWindow_?

Comment: add the following at the end of the constructor of _MainWindow_ (after `parentLayout->setContentsMargins(0,0,40,0);`): `auto *l = new QVBoxLayout(this);
 l->addWidget(scrollArea);`

Comment: @scopchanov Your question does not make sense, that is, the MainWindow class must necessarily inherit from QMainWindow, where is it indicated?

Comment: @eyllanesc, I am asking if there is a special reason not to inherit from _QMainWindow_.

Comment: @eyllanesc, because if he inherits from _QMainWindow_, the solution would be to just add: `setCentralWidget(scrollArea);`.

Comment: @scopchanov mmm, but it would be to modify what the asker wants, do not you think?, the solution is just to set a layout to the widget, and in that layout to set the QScrollArea, that is similar to setCentralWidget.

Comment: @eyllanesc, you're right. That's why my next comment was proposing this solution with the layout.

Comment: @scopchanov I also think that this question has been asked many times, later I will search for a duplicate. :)

Comment: @eyllanesc, that's why I am not in a hurry to start composing an answer ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178021/discussion-between-scopchanov-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: The above code is a part of a custom widget,so I inherited QWidget and not QMainWindow.

Comment: @adi, and does the solution work for you?

Comment: @scopchanov..Its working man..apologies for the delayed reply..could you add this as answer..

Comment: @scopchanov..could you add this as answer so that I can mark it and could u pls brief the significance of those lines so that I can understand the solution correctly....

Comment: @scopchanov:If you dont mind,could you have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52426751/qtunable-to-set-custom-widget-background-color-border-width] question!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is, that I want the scrollArea to occupy the entire
>   window, but it does not. It also doesn't get resized when I resize the window.

The reason is that you have not set any kind of layout to manage the positioning of your `QScrollArea` widget itself, so it is just being left to its own devices (and therefore it just chooses a default size-and-location for itself and stays at that size-and-location).

A simple fix would be to add these lines to the bottom of your `MainWindow` constructor:

```
QBoxLayout * mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
mainLayout->setMargin(0);
mainLayout->addWidget(scrollArea);
```