# How to set a custom widget's background color and border width?

Tags: c++, qt, background-color, qwidget, qtstylesheets

I have a custom widget whose parent is yet another custom widget. I am able to set the background color of the parent custom widget using `QPalette` and it works fine. But I am unable to set the child custom widget's border color using both `QPalette` and `stylesheet`.

This is how I set my parent custom widget's background color:

```
QPalette pal = parentCustomWidget->palette();
QColor color = {226, 208, 208};
pal.setColor (QPalette::Background, color);
parentCustomWidget->setAutoFillBackground (true);
parentCustomWidget->setPalette (pal);
parentCustomWidget->show();
```

I referred several SO posts/answers for setting background color to custom widget, but I am unable to set it. This is how I set my `childCustomWidget`'s color:

Approach1:

```
QPalette pal = childCustomWidget->palette();
QColor color = {204, 231, 47};
pal.setColor (QPalette::Background, color);
childCustomWidget->setAutoFillBackground (true);
childCustomWidget->setPalette (pal);
```

Approach2:

```
childCustomWidget->setStyleSheet ("*{border-width:" +
    BorderThickness +
    ";border-style:solid;border-color:" +
    hexColorCode + " ;color:white;}");
```

**Note:** I have commented out the `paintEvent` virtual function.

I have gone through this link: [How to Change the Background Color of QWidget](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Change_the_Background_Color_of_QWidget) and have incorporated changes like given but im unable to set color to `childCustomWidget`.

My custom widgets with the above approaches look like this:

[image: this]

Here orange is the parent's BG color which I am able to set. The grey colored one seems to be the default color for the child widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

For *Approach2* to work, i.e. for your custom widget to respect the stylesheet, the [Qt::WA_StyledBackground](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) attribute should be set to `true`, as it:

> Indicates the widget should be drawn using a styled background.

## Example

Here is a minimal example I have prepared for you in order to demonstrate a possible implementation of the suggested solution:

```
class ParentWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ParentWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QWidget(parent) {}
};

class ChildWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ChildWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QWidget(parent) {}
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0) :
           QMainWindow(parent)
       {
           auto *pWidget = new ParentWidget(this);
           auto *l = new QVBoxLayout(pWidget);
           auto *cWidget = new ChildWidget(pWidget);
           QString BorderThickness("2");
           QString hexColorCode("#FF00FF");

           l->addWidget(cWidget);
           l->setContentsMargins(25, 25, 25, 25);

           QPalette pal(pWidget->palette());
           QColor color(226, 208, 208);
           pal.setColor (QPalette::Background, color);
           pWidget->setAutoFillBackground (true);
           pWidget->setPalette (pal);

           cWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_StyledBackground, true);
           cWidget->setStyleSheet("ChildWidget { border: " + BorderThickness + " solid " +
                                  hexColorCode + ";"
                                                 "background-color: rgb(204, 231, 47);"
                                                 "color: white; }");

           setCentralWidget(pWidget);
           resize (400, 400);
       }
};
```

## Result

As it is written, this example produces the following result:

[image: Window showing a colored rectangle with a border on a colored background]

Comment: Thanks for the response @scopchanov:When I tried the example :it gives me "undefined reference to vtable" error ..So I commented out Q_OBJECT macro,now it shows only parent widget color and not the child widget's color...

Comment: @adi, on my Windows machine this compiles just fine. I have just tested it on Ubuntu as well. Did you add the includes?

Comment: @adi You can have this kind of vtable error on Q_OBJECT when qmake/make do not generate the moc file during compilation. This generally happens when using MSVC. In this case re-running `qmake` by hand (`Run qmake` in the context menu in Qt Creator) can solve the issue.

Comment: @BenjaminT, I also clean the project first. Just in case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @scopchanov..I reinstalled qt and tried ur example..it works!! Could u tell me if there is a way to set border color of the widget using QPalette itself instead of stylesheets?

Comment: @adi, unfortunately there isn't. Though you can paint the border in a paint event using a color from the palette.

Comment: @scopchanov ...could u brief me how can I do that in paintEvent?

Comment: @adi, take a look at [this](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/styles/qdrawutil.cpp.html#_Z14qDrawPlainRectP8QPainteriiiiRK6QColoriPK6QBrush).

Comment: Hi scopchanov,when I try to increase my border thickness,Im unable to see the contents of the widget.I have posted a new question,could you have a look at it pls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52697845/qt-border-color-of-qwidget-hiding-the-contents]!!

Answer (score -1):

Qt docs about palette: **Warning**: Do not use this function in conjunction with Qt Style Sheets. When using style sheets, the palette of a widget can be customized using the "color", "background-color", "selection-color", "selection-background-color" and "alternate-background-color".

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#palette-prop

Qt docs about autoFillBackground: **Warning**: Use this property with caution in conjunction with Qt Style Sheets. When a widget has a style sheet with a valid background or a border-image, this property is automatically disabled.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#autoFillBackground-prop